# PHP: Is there an path specification convention?

Tags: php

One problem I see all over the place is the big question: "must I put an / in front of a path, or must I not?"

Sorry if this appears subjective, but for my framework it's an important question: 
Do you think that it's more logical to put a "/" in front of every path when specifying one, or do you think the "/" prefix should be avoided?

Or should I check if the first char is "/" and if not, add that automatically?

Context: Framework functions that take paths.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand you. Do you mean file paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put a `/` in front of every path, then those paths are absolute. Without it, they are relative. Not sure what you're after, but that's what the `/` at the beginning is for.

For example, if your current directory is `/var/www/html/` and you give your path as `foo/bar/`, the path becomes `/var/www/html/foo/bar/`.

If you give your path as `/foo/bar/`, then the path is just that, with nothing prepended.

So the forward slash is just a matter of where you're looking the files from, and if you're using the paths as a argument to a function, you probably want to pass them as relative (to the framework directory).

Comment: But if the framework performs "root-jailing" and considers all paths starting from the same basedir, then it won't really matter, will it?

Answer (score 1):

The best convention is whether or not you intend the path to be relative or absolute.  Generally, a leading '/' specifies an absolute path, from the root of a file system, or the root of a website.

Take an example CSS file, located at at mysite.com/files/css/info.css

```
...
background-image:url('/bg.png'); /* absolute - use mysite.com/bg.png */
background-image:url('bg.png');  /* relative to info.css - use mysite.com/files/css/bg.png */
...
```

In your own code, when you have an option of ommitting or including a leading slash, you can follow a similar convention:

```
<?php

// $uri - the relative/absolute uri to link to, ie /posts or 'show/id'
// $text - the text link
function link_to($uri, $text) {

  if ($uri[0] == '/') {
    // assume absolute
    $href = $uri;
  } else {
    // assume relative to current uri; remove last segment and replace
    $uri_segments = get_uri_segments();
    array_pop($uri_segments);
    array_push($uri_segments, $uri);
    $href = implode('/', $uri_segments);
  }

  return "<a href=\"$href\">$text</a>";
}

//
// elsewhere, assuming current URL is 'myself.com/users'
//

// relative link to 'create'
link_to("create", "Show User"); // mysite.com/users/create

// absolute link to '/products'
link_to("/products", "Products"); // mysite.com/products

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to have it because it makes it easier to add on files and it avoids confusion to always have it. For example:

```
http://example.com/ + file.php IS http://example.com/file.php = path
http://example.com + file.php IS http://example.comfile.php = error
```